# for loop of set to print only unique dictionary items

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary, set

I have defined a string read in from a file as such

```
str = """foo\t1039|1736|t3958\n
frombric\t1039\n
bonn\t\n"""
```

that I want outputted as such:

```
1039\tfoo
1736\tfoo
3958\tfoo
```

Note that the duplicate gene (1039) is only outputted once, associated with the first occurring description. Also note that there might be no numbers (genes) associated with a descriptor (bonn, in this case)

My approach was to add the genes redundantly as lists of strings to a dictionary, while also maintaining a set of the genes, which I finally use to pull out the genes for each key in a *for* loop.
According to me, the code below must result in an out-print of only unique genes, since the final *for* loop iterates over unique values in a set. However, though things are running and I get my desired shape of output, but I am very puzzled as to why it doesn't always seem to be the case that the list only contains UNIQUE genes..

```
for filename in fileList:
f = open("filename")
data = f.readlines()    
    uniquegene = set()
    d = defaultdict(list)

    for line in data:
       parts = line.split('\t')
       desc = parts[0]
       try: 
          genes = parts[1].split('|')
          d[desc] += genes
          for gene in genes:
             uniquegene.append(i)
       except IndexError:
          print " there are no genes on this line"

   result=""
   for u in uniquegene:
        result += "%s\t%s\t%s\n" % (u, filename [key for key in d if u in d[key]])
   print result
```

I'd really appreciate some help trying to find my bug. (the code above is a bit simplified from my code). Thank you.

Comment: I forgot the line `d[desc] += genes`; Added it to the script. Thanks.

Comment: Does that make any sense..? I started to wonder if my last list comprehension makes sense - What i want there is: give me the keys in the dictionary for every item in the set which is present as a value in the dictionaries'value lists...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't quite understand why you're maintaining both a set of unique genes, and a dictionary of *descriptor* to list of genes. I'd think what you'd want to do is build a dictionary of Descriptor -> Set of Genes, unless you also need to maintain a dictionary with the complete ordered list of all occurrences of a gene for each descriptor as well:

```
d = defaultdict(set)

for line in data:
   parts = line.split('\t')
   desc = parts[0]
   try: 
      genes = parts[1].split('|')
      for gene in genes:
         d['desc'].add(gene)
   except IndexError:
      print " there are no genes on this line"
```

If you need to maintain the complete (non-unique) dictionary, then I would keep that as your true data representation, and filter the results when you output them:

```
for k,v in d.iteritems():
    for g in set(v):
        result += "%s\t%s\n" % (g, k)
print result
```

Comment: When I run it like this I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack` at the `for k,v in d:` statement. The difference with your and my code seems that in the way I add the genes (as one big list of strings to the dictionary, while in your case the genes get added one by one -if I understand..) Does that make a difference? Thanks.

Comment: @user3524881 Bah, sorry - made my usual mistake when iterating over a python `dict`. Corrected now, but it should have read `for k,v in d.iteritems():`. Apologies.

Comment: Thanks I tried this earlier I think. This doesn't give the disired output. My What happens is that i end up with huge file, where many genes are repeated multiple times and the desc's come on different lines expect on one line as a list. I'm not having an issue any more though I'd like to understand better why this happens. thanks.